Creating new Firebase functions project using Node.js 20 - Error "Package subpath './lib/logger' is not defined"
Due to ending GCP Runtime support I created a new project to migrate my functions to Node.js 20.
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/runtime-support#support_schedule
I followed the instructions on the link below and created a new project, changed the Node version in package.json to 20.
  "engines": {
    "node": "20"
  },

I also changed the eslintrc.js to use ES 2022
  parserOptions: {
    "ecmaVersion": 2022,
  },

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd
Although the guide had a few shortcomings, the process was pretty straight forward.
(It was missing information for Linux users, and needed a full read-thru before beginning, since the information was not presented in an optimal order. Also, the guide did not instruct to use the easier firebase init command, for some reason.)
After pasting my old code and installing packages npm install I tried to deploy.
The deploy gives me an error, though.
$ firebase deploy --only "functions:testFunction"


Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/logger'
is not defined by "exports" in
/home/my/Documents/projects/api-v2/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/package.json

The file is handled by npm, but I tried to add the missing import anyways.
  "exports": {
    ".": "./lib/v1/index.js",
    "./logger/compat": "./lib/logger/compat.js",
    "./logger": "./lib/logger/index.js",
    "./lib/logger": "./lib/logger/index.js", <-- ADDED LINE

After adding the import, I get another error that point s to a file that does not exist.
$ firebase deploy --only "functions:testFunction"


Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/logger'
is not defined by "exports" in
/home/my/Documents/projects/api-v2/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/package.json

I also followed the upgrade guide (missing a lot of info on realtime database), but that made no difference --> https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade
So, what am I doing wrong?
The error messages gives vague clues to what is wrong.
EDIT
I realised I need to replace all logging from this:
const debug = require("firebase-functions/lib/logger").debug;
const error = require("firebase-functions/lib/logger").error;
const info = require("firebase-functions/lib/logger").info;

to this:
const { logger } = require("firebase-functions");
// Usage: logger.info("");

However, the deploy still fails!
The error messages and log does not help much!

i  functions: creating Node.js 20 (2nd Gen) function
testEmailSend(us-central1)... ⚠  functions: HTTP Error: 500,
Validation failed for trigger
projects/my-api2/locations/us-central1/triggers/testfunction-524954:
An internal error has occurred (87ae4239-49e6-4769-9bf8-7571bad79245)
⚠  functions:  failed to create function
projects/my-api2/locations/us-central1/functions/testFunction
Failed to create function
projects/my-api2/locations/us-central1/functions/testFunction
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
testFunction(us-central1) i  functions: cleaning up build files... ⚠  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This
could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt
to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually
at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/idhammar-api2/us/gcf
Error: There was an error deploying functions

So, what is causing the 500 response when deploying?
Kind regards
/K

Shouldn't require("firebase-functions/lib/logger") be require("firebase-functions/logger")? Also that error says you should go to the Google Cloud Console and delete the bugged out image(s) (in this context, an image is a snapshot of your deployed code from the last time you attempted deployment). Once you delete them, you can redeploy your functions.

Thanks for the reply! :D The code is old v1 that works, but that seems wrong now that you point it out. I have remedied the log errors now! :D
I deleted the images, but still cannot deploy. :(

I found one container that was still hanging around, thanks!
Now I get a differrent error :D
"The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information."

I want to thank samthecodingman for the correct answer!
Deleting the bugged out image(s) solved the issue!
